# Bulk Insert a CSV file into MongoDB through Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: mongodb, csv

I'm trying to performance test MongoDB through Ubuntu, and I've run into problems trying to upload a CSV file to populate the database.

My DB is called 'Assignment' and I want to create a collection: 'Airport'. My CSV file is located inmy Ubuntu desktop file.

I've tried both the following commands:

> mongoimport --db Assignment --collection Airport --type csv --headerline -–ignoreblanks --file Aircraft.csv
>
> mongoimport --db Assignment --collection Airport --type csv --headerline -–ignoreblanks --file /home/jon/Desktop/Aircraft.csv

...but get the following error in both instances:
2014-07-20T03:01:41.273-0700 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Please can anyone advise where I'm going wrong?

Greatly appreciate any help.
R,
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

There were someproblems with the syntax, but also, I was trying to run from within the mongodb.exe, and the import needed to be run from the bin$ level, like this:-

```
jon@ubuntu:~/Desktop/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.3/bin$ mongoimport --db jontestcsv --collection Aircraft --ignoreBlanks --type csv --headerline --file /home/jon/Desktop/Aircraft.csv
```